# Select the li element only once on mousemove

Tags: javascript

I have a list of li elements.

I'm trying to select these elements upon mouseclick + mousemove. 
However, it is selecting the same elements several times inside my mousemove function:

```
this.querySelector('.directory-list').addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {

        this.querySelector('.directory-list').onmousemove = function(e) {
          this._target = (e.target) ? e.target: e.srcElement;
          this._target.select();      
        } 
 });
```

Let's say I have something like this:
[image]

If I want to select these two directories with my mouse, it would select them about 10 times because of my "onmousemove" function.

Is there any way to get rid of duplicates while doing that ?

Comment: `.querySelector('.directory-list')` return the first matched item (In you case it will always select one element, the first).

Comment: Right after selecting item, set onmousemove to null, so it won't be called again.

Answer (score 1):

You could check to see if __target is defined and then only define/select it if not.

```
this.querySelector('.directory-list').addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
        this.querySelector('.directory-list').onmousemove = function(e) {
            if (!this_target) {
               this._target = (e.target) ? e.target: e.srcElement;
               this._target.select();      
            }
        } 
 });
```

then set it to null on mouseup.

Comment: did exactly like that! Doesn't work. For the first mousedown + mousemove it selects only the first element. When mouseup happens it doesn't allow to select even the first element.

Comment: What about defining the target outside the functions?  I think the problem might be that you're setting this._target and it's getting lost after the event stops firing.